# Facebook login wont open login dialog objective-c

Tags: objective-c, facebook, authentication, sigabrt

am trying to complete the tutorial for the iOS SDK 3.0 from Facebook and I have an error after pressing (log in with Facebook) button.

```
0x10b4b9683 <+241>: jmp    0x10b4b95ae               ; <+28> at FBSDKInternalUtility.m:491
```

"Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your Info.plist file and make sure "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" has an item labelled "fbauth2" instead of "fbauth".